# Is it possible to change Google Chrome's previous/next tabs shortcuts?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to change Google Chrome's previous/next tabs shortcut (⌘+Option+← and ⌘+Option+→) to ⌘+Shift+← and ⌘+Shift+→ instead?

I use both Safari and Chrome (for different purposes) and bounce between them quite often.

In Safari, the shortcut to go to the previous/next tab is  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>←</kbd>   and  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>  <kbd>→</kbd> . I'm quite used to this to move between my tabs. I've even set this up to be my shortcut to go between my Mac's Finder tabs, and it's the combo I prefer.

However, with Chrome, the shortcut uses  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  in place of  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> .

This breaks my muscle memory whenever I need to do the same in Chrome after having used Safari/Finder.

Is there any way I can change the shortcuts in Chrome to be like Safari's?

I'm on macOS Monterey 12.4 and the latest version of Chrome (102.0.5005.61 as of this writing) if it matters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this for anything that has a menu item, any app or all apps*, so long as it doesn't clash with another function or a global command.

Chrome default…

[image]

System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts

Click the + button, select an app [or all apps, if appropriate]
Type the ***exact*** name of the menu item - especially important for those with an ellipsis … which is not the same as just three stops ...
Note that unless the same command appears twice in one app's menu set [rare but possible] then you don't need to specify *where* it is, it will find it, even down sub-menus. If there *is* a double, you can specify which using  `menu->submenu->name` syntax
Add your key command. Click Add.
Done. [You don't even need to close the prefs pane, it's immediate.]

[image]

After changing both…

[image]

You can, of course, also use this to add key commands to menu items that don't already have one - and, if you want to disable one.. you cannot strictly disable it, but you can change it to comething you'll never hit by accident, like  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>F12</kbd>

Like this…

[image]

btw, if you weren't aware, they do both already share the same [alternative but still default] key commands for next/last tab
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>]</kbd>  and  <kbd>[</kbd>

Also, this is not OS-dependent. As far as I'm aware it's been available since very early OS X. [Periodically the graphics change a bit, photos above from Mojave] but functionality has been long standard.

*Note: You can only control 'regular' app this way. You cannot control apps that are only in the right side menu bar. They are never frontmost so don't respond in the same way.