# How do I change Chrome's full-screen mode keyboard shortcut from the command line?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to change [the default Chrome keyboard shortcut, ctrl+cmd+f](https://www.lifewire.com/activate-full-screen-mode-google-chrome-4103634), to something else, and I would like to do so through a command-line, so that I can share it across my computers using Chezmoi.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually no idea how to add this through command line - but I know where it goes once you've added the command…

For how to add the command, see [Is it possible to change Google Chrome's previous/next tabs shortcuts?](https://superuser.com/questions/1724835/is-it-possible-to-change-google-chromes-previous-next-tabs-shortcuts)

…though in this case you'll need to add two versions, each with the same key, because the wording changes & you cannot add a single command to a context-sensitive menu, you need to anticipate all necessary contexts.

In System prefs, you add this [or command of your choice]…

[image]

which then adds an entry to Chrome's user plist, in `~/Library/Preferences/com.google.Chrome.plist`

```
    <dict>
        <key>Enter Full Screen</key>
        <string>@~^$f</string>
        <key>Exit Full Screen</key>
        <string>@~^$f</string>
    </dict>
```

I don't know which modifier key is which in this, so I used all 4 to give you a head start.

So, you need to either be able to propagate this addition to all your 'client' Macs, or push the file itself.

Comment: Excellent. I wrote a short script for Chezmoi that sets this: https://gist.github.com/gregorias/83206028a7a55fb13aec4c748ca9723b